# Opera clears localStorage onLoad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, opera

I wan't to grab a user that is stored in localStorage(user) when the client loads the page.

OPERA somehow **won't grab it** and it load createUser() **every time**

**Status**:
Chrome: OK,
Firefox: OK,
Edge: won't even ask for user ?!

```
userProfile = {
    userName : localStorage.getItem("user")
}

if(localStorage.user){
  loadUser();
}
else{
    createUser();
}
```

These are my functions....

```
function loadUser(){

  console.log("Laddar",userProfile.userName +"'s profil" );
  $('#userMessage').html("Välkommen " + userProfile.userName);
}

function createUser(){

  var newUser = prompt("Vad heter du?");
  if (newUser === null) {
    return;
  }
  else{

    // Here i set the user
    localStorage.setItem("user", newUser);
    console.log("Hi", newUser);
    $('#userMessage').html("Welcome" + newUser);
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try using `getItem()`?

Comment: I do it when the document is loaded by loading a global Object variable (userProfile) that recieve **localStorage.getItem("user")**

it works in Chrome and Mozilla.....hmm